# Problem with minecraft code 1.16.5 and org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard

Tags: java, minecraft, lwjgl

I have a code of my minecraft mod.

```
package com.StilShem.BetterPH.keys;

import com.StilShem.BetterPH.Client;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class key {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent e) {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.getEventKey())) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKey() != Keyboard.KEY_NONE) {
                Client.keyPress(Keyboard.getEventKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is code for Minecraft version 1.12.2
On version 1.16.5 no package "org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard"
I need to change this code for version 1.16.5.

Answer (score 0):

If this is LWJGL 3, then it doesn't work because there *is* no Keyboard class for LWJGL 3. The Keyboard class in LWJGL 2 was removed in LWJGL 3.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is how to update the code provided for (a version of Minecraft that uses) LWJGL 3.